# rewrite works for = but not for <-> (iff) in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have the following during a proof, in which I need to replace `normal_form step t` with `value t` as there is a proven theorem that there are equivalent.

```
H1 : t1 ==>* t1' /\ normal_form step t1'
t2' : tm
H2 : t2 ==>* t2' /\ normal_form step t2'
______________________________________(1/1)
exists t' : tm, P t1 t2 ==>* t' /\ normal_form step t'
```

The equivalence theorem is:

```
Theorem nf_same_as_value
 : forall t : tm, normal_form step t <-> value t
```

Now, I can use this theorem to rewrite `normal_form` occurrences in the hypotheses, ***but not*** in the goal. That is

```
rewrite nf_same_as_value in H1; rewrite nf_same_as_value in H2.
```

works on the hypothesis, but `rewrite nf_same_as_value.` on the goal gives:

```
Error:
Found no subterm matching "normal_form step ?4345" in the current goal.
```

Is the `rewrite` on the goal here impossible theoretically, or is it an implementation issue?

-- Edit --

My confusion here is that if we define `normal_form step = value`, the rewrite would have worked. If we define `forall t, normal_form step t <-> value t`, then the `rewrite` works if `normal_form step` is not quoted in an existential, but does not work if it is in an existential.

Adapting @Matt 's example,

```
Require Export Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Inductive R1 : Prop -> Prop -> Prop :=
|T1_refl : forall P, R1 P P.

Inductive R2 : Prop -> Prop -> Prop :=
|T2_refl : forall P, R2 P P.

Theorem Requal : R1 = R2. 
Admitted. 

Theorem Requiv : forall x y, R1 x y <-> R2 x y. 
Admitted. 

Theorem test0 : forall y, R2 y y -> exists x, R1 x x. 
Proof.
  intros. rewrite <- Requal in H. (*works*) rewrite Requal. (*works as well*) 

Theorem test2 : forall y, R2 y y -> exists x, R1 x x. 
Proof.
  intros. rewrite <- Requiv in H. (*works*) rewrite Requiv. (*fails*)
```

What confuses me is why the last step has to fail.

```
1 subgoal
y : Prop
H : R1 y y
______________________________________(1/1)
exists x : Prop, R1 x x
```

Is this failure related to functional extensionality?

The error message is particularly confusing:

```
Error:
Found no subterm matching "R1 ?P ?P0" in the current goal.
```

There is exactly one subterm matching `R1 _ _`, namely R1 x x.

Also, per @larsr, the rewrite works if `eexists` is used

```
Theorem test1 : forall y, R2 y y -> exists x, R1 x x. 
Proof.
  intros. eexists. rewrite Requiv. (*works as well*) apply H. Qed.
```

What did `eexists` add here?

Answer (score 4):

The rewrite cannot go under the existential quantifier.  You'll need to instantiate `t'` first before you can do the rewrite.  Note that `econstructor` may be a useful tactic in this case, which can replace the existential quantifier with a unification variable.

**EDIT in response to OP's comment**

This will still not work for equality.  As an example, try:

```
Inductive R1 : Prop -> Prop -> Prop :=
|T1_refl : forall P, R1 P P.

Inductive R2 : Prop -> Prop -> Prop :=
|T2_refl : forall P, R2 P P.

Theorem Req : forall x y, R1 x y = R2 x y. 
Admitted. 

Theorem test : forall y, R2 y y -> exists x, R1 x x. 
Proof.
  intros. rewrite Req. (*rewrite still fails*)
```

The issue is not actually about equality vs. iff, the issue relates to rewriting under a binding (in this case a lambda).  [The implementation](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Logic.html) of `exists x : A, P` is really just syntax for `ex A (fun x => P x)`, so the rewrite is failing not because of the iff, but because the `rewrite` tactic does not want to go under the binding for `x` in `(fun x => P x)`.  It seems as though there might be a way to do this with [setoid_rewrite](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual029.html#sec756), however, I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: Thanks. But part of my question is that I don't see why rewrite shouldn't go into existential quantifiers. I imagine if it's an equality instead of iff, `rewrite` would have worked here, wouldn't it?

Comment: @tinlyx I've added an edit that might clear things up.

Comment: @Matt, thanks, I added an update using your example.

Comment: `Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.` and then `setoid_rewrite Requiv.` should work under the existential quantifier.