# Rewrite equivalence under exists in goal

Tags: coq, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I've proved an equivalence `and_distributes_over_or`:

```
Theorem and_distributes_over_or : forall P Q R : Prop,
  P /\ (Q \/ R) <-> (P /\ Q) \/ (P /\ R).
```

Elsewhere I have a goal of

```
exists x0 : A, f x0 = y /\ (x = x0 \/ In x0 xs)
```

(For context I'm working through [Logical Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html); I'm on [the `In_map_iff` exercise of the chapter on constructive logic](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Logic.html#lab181). Please don't tell me the solution to the exercise though!)

I tried to use `rewrite and_distributes_over_or` on my goal (to get `exists x0 : A, (f x0 = y /\ x = x0) \/ (f x0 = y /\ In x0 xs)`). I got an error:

```
Found no subterm matching "?P /\ (?P0 \/ ?P1)" in the current goal.
```

Using my human brain I can see what seems to be a very obvious subterm of that form in the goal. Why can't Coq, with its non-human non-brain, see it under the existential quantifier? Do you have any tips to make this work?

I've read [a previous question with a similar title to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635697/rewrite-under-exists) but that's about rewriting in hypotheses, not goals, and the answer doesn't appear to be applicable to my situation.

Comment: @StephenC It's [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), which is a programming language for automated theorem proving. Plenty of similar questions in [the `coq` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coq), definitely not off topic for SO.

Comment: No disrespect taken. If we're being facetious, [all programming is theorem proving and all theorem proving is programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), so Stack Overflow and Mathematics SE shouldn't really be different sites in the first place . To address your direct point, Coq is indeed a programming language. It just happens to be a programming language specifically designed to be useful for proving things (much as Erlang is a programming language specifically designed to be useful for distributed computing).

Comment: Take it to Meta. There are already >1000 questions in [the `coq` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coq).

Comment: OK ... I accept (based on Wikipedia) that `coq` is BOTH a functional programming language AND a formal proof system.  I have updated the tag wiki.

Comment: @StephenC Even if Coq was considered only a formal proof system, then I'd think this question still belongs here, since it's not really about mathematics or logic. It's about how to make the tool do what one wants. And in this case this is purely technical stuff. But if this question was about the underlying theory of Coq, then I'd agree with you as CS.SE (or CStheory.SE) would be a much better place.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239906/rewrite-works-for-but-not-for-iff-in-coq) is sort of related (I'm putting the link here so the people who'd find the linked question could come here and see this concise exposition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `setoid_rewrite` instead of `rewrite`, and make sure to `Require Setoid.` (though loading `List` has already done so in this case).

The pattern Coq is looking for is underneath a binder; that is, it's in the body of a function. The binder isn't obvious because it's part of the `exists`, but your goal is actually `ex (fun (x0:A) => f x0 = y /\ (x = x0 \/ In x0 xs))`, and Coq's notation mechanism prints it nicely as `exists x0, ...`. The basic `rewrite` tactic can't do rewrites inside functions, but `setoid_rewrite` can.

Aside: note that the definition `ex` and its notation `exists x, ...` aren't built-in to Coq but are defined in the standard library! You can inspect these sort of things with `Locate exists` (to find the notation) and `Print ex` (to view the definition). There's also `Unset Printing Notations.` if you're not sure what notations are in use, though bear in mind that there are a lot of notations you probably take for granted, like `/\`, `=`, and even `->`.

Comment: Thank you very much, `setoid_rewrite` did the trick and I learned something about `exists`! How come `setoid_rewrite` can see inside lambdas but `rewrite` can't? Does `rewrite` work with relations less powerful than equivalences?

Comment: It's actually not about the relation; `rewrite` already falls back on `setoid_rewrite` when not using equality as the relation. The documentation (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html?highlight=setoid_rewrite#rewriting-under-binders) says that rewrite doesn't go under binders for compatibility reasons; going under binders could change the behavior of a lot of existing rewrites.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Thanks for your patience!